# Error in lineDevSpecific (login in the phone)

Tags: c#, mobile, authentication, tapi, avaya

I am trying to do `login` in the phone. I am developing in `c#` and the library is in `C++`. The function **"lineDevSpecific" returns the value "-2147483595"**, but it must to be positive.

```
[DllImport("Tapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    unsafe private static extern int lineDevSpecific(IntPtr hLine, IntPtr lpParams);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct UserRec
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public int dwMode=8;
        public int dwParam1=201;
        public int dwParam2=0;
    }

    unsafe static void Iniciar()
    {

        string vline = "Ip Office Phone: 201";
        IntPtr hline = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(vline);

        var sizeUserRec = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(UserRec));
        var userRec = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeUserRec);
        int result=lineDevSpecific(hline, userRec);
        var x = (UserRec)Marshal.PtrToStructure(userRec, typeof(UserRec));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(userRec);
    }
```

Version 2:

I have modified the initial post adding the lineInitializeEx method and lineOpen. 
These methods returns a positive value, after this lineDevSpecific continues returning the same value.

```
[DllImport("Tapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    unsafe private static extern long lineInitializeEx(ref uint lphLineApp, uint hInstance, uint lpfnCallback, uint lpszFriendlyAppName, ref uint lpdwNumDevs, ref uint lpdwAPIVersion, ref uint lpLineInitializeExParams);
    [DllImport("Tapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern long lineOpen(ref uint hLineApp, uint dwDeviceID, uint lphLine, uint dwAPIVersion, uint dwExtVersion, uint dwCallbackInstance, uint dwPrivileges, uint dwMediaModes, ref uint lpCallParams);
    [DllImport("Tapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    unsafe private static extern int lineDevSpecific(uint hLine, IntPtr lpParams);
        uint lineApp = 0;
        uint numdevs = 0;
        uint apiversion = 0;
        uint exparams = 0;
        uint lpcallparams = 0;
        string sParams = "";
        long lSize = 0;
        long inicio = lineInitializeEx(ref lineApp, 0, 0, 0, ref numdevs, ref apiversion, ref exparams);
        if (inicio > 0)
        {
            long open = lineOpen(ref lineApp, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ref lpcallparams);
            //string vline = "Ip Office Phone: 201";
            //IntPtr hline = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(vline);

            var sizeUserRec = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(UserRec));
            var userRec = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeUserRec);
            int result = lineDevSpecific(lineApp, userRec);
            var x = (UserRec)Marshal.PtrToStructure(userRec, typeof(UserRec));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(userRec);
        }
```

Solution: I have called to Julmar Atapi.

```
string extension = "201";
            char[] c = new char[extension.Length + 2];
            c[0] = (char)0x08; //login character

            int i = 1;
            foreach (char s in extension)
            {
                c[i] = s;
                i++;
            }
            c[i] = (char)0x00; //null terminator
            CurrentAddress.DeviceSpecific(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a LINEERR_ constant, see [MSDN LINEERR_ Constants page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735630(v=vs.85).aspx)

These use a hexadecimal unsigned "0x8000 00xx" style, turning them negative if you look at them as a signed int.

So this one is 0x8000 0035 LINEERR_INVALPOINTER

Your hline is wrong, this is a handle to a line not a text in a pointer. You need to get it from a [lineOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms736005(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Update for version 2**

You are mixing up hLineApp and hLine. From [lineOpen MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms736005(v=vs.85).aspx):

> hLineApp: Handle to the application's registration with TAPI.
>
> lphLine: Pointer to an HLINE handle that is then loaded with the handle representing the opened line device. Use this handle to identify the device when invoking other functions on the open line device.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have changed the post adding code. I have two lines: Ip Office Phone: 201 and Ip Office Phone: 202. I understand that lineApp is initial value 0 ("Line 201") and after this I have to send by reference the lineApp value.

Comment: lineDefSpecific has mire parameter than you provided. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735604(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: rhdez7, may I suggest you take a look at http://atapi.codeplex.com/ It is not perfect but it's the best example I know of working with TAPI from .NET. It may help you with some of the basics

Comment: I have solved this using Atapi from Julmar. I have changed my post. Thanks.